# How can I select the item that doesn't have attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I mean, like I would like to style the element that has not attribute `title` like `[!title] /*This doesnt work*/` how can I do this with CSS selectors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
*:not([title])
```

This will select everything that does `not` have attribute `title`.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/gkFbh/) for an example.

Comment: There is an exact duplicate (just saying)!